# Coordinating rust channels across thread pools

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I'm not sure that code will help me on this one, so I'll do my best to explain the complexity of my scenario:

I have pools of threads, Pool A and Pool B.

**Pool A** is a dedicated set of workers that are listening to their own mpsc channel.  Each worker communicates periodically based on an internal timer, but upon receiving a message from the mpsc channel, it must immediately respond.  This functionality is working perfectly.

**Pool B** is a set of workers that take really long-running tasks and do calculations.  If the calculations exceed certain thresholds, they need to notify the proper worker in pool A via the mpsc channel.

### The Problem

If I try to send a message from the main thread to Pool A without actually spawning the workers of pool B, I can send messages with no issues.  However, once I've actually moved the send code inside of the spawned pool B, I run into major lifetime errors from the rust compiler.

### My Implementation

I'm creating the communication channels as such:

`let (sender, mut receiver) = mpsc::channel(32);`

I'm adding the channels to a HashMap for later reference:

`let mut worker_senders: HashMap<i32, mpsc::Sender<String>> = HashMap::new();`

In Pool B, I wanted to send a message to a specific worker in Pool A by calling:

```
let worker:i32 = 5;
if let Some(sender) = worker_senders.get(worker){
   sender.send("alert".to_string()).await.expect("Failed to send message.");
}
```

worker_senders is actually a RefCell, and if I comment out the `sender.send(...)` line, the code compiles and the surrounding code works as intended.

But trying to include the `sender.send(...)` line is failing due to worker_senders failing to implement Send for the tokio::spawn -- at least that was the essence of the error message I received.

I feel like this type of thread pool A talking to thread pool B should be fairly common, so I must be missing something.  Maybe I'm approaching this completely backwards.

Any suggestions/advice?

------ EDIT ------

The following is a more complete code example that is enough to show the full progression to get the error.  It's entirely possible that some of it is unnecessary -- I'm not exactly a seasoned rust veteran, yet.

```
let mut worker_sender: HashMap<i32, mpsc::Sender<String>> = HashMap::new();
let worker_sender_rc = RefCell::new(worker_sender);
let cloned_worker_sender_rc = worker_sender_rc.clone();

tokio::spawn (async move {
   #[derive(Clone)]
   struct OcMessage {
      sender: i32,
      message: String, 
   };
 
   let m = parse_packet(data);
   let mut borrowed_worker_sender = cloned_worker_sender_rc.borrow();
   let msg = OcMessage {sender: 15, message: "alert".to_string()};
   if let Some(sender) = borrowed_worker_sender.get(&msg.sender) {
      let tmp_msg = msg.message;
      sender.send(tmp_msg).await.expect("Couldn't send message,");
   }
});
```

This gives the following error:

```
 = help: within `[async block@src/main.rs:563:31: 579:18]`, the trait `std::marker::Send` is not implemented for `NonNull<HashMap<i32, tokio::sync::mpsc::Sender<Utf8String>>>`
note: future is not `Send` as this value is used across an await
```

Comment: `RefCell::get` doesn't exist. Are you sure `worker_senders` is a `RefCell`? `worker_senders.get()` should not compile. Or is `worker_senders` the result of calling `RefCell::borrow*()`?

Comment: Yes, you're correct.   ```let worker_senders = worker_sender_rc.borrow_mut();``` is actually how I'm getting the reference. I was trying to balance the need for brevity with clarity on my approach.  The actual code is several thousand lines and I'm trying to figure out why the send().await is causing the issue.  I might be using the wrong approach altogether, so I was trying to ask in such a way to make that clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RefCell` is not thread-safe because its internal reference count is not maintained atomically, so it does not implement `Send` or `Sync`. Because of this, the `Ref` and `RefMut` types returned from `borrow()` and `borrow_mut()` respectively also don't implement these traits. This means if you hold a `Ref` or `RefMut` across an await point, the generated future won't implement `Send`.

Commenting out the `sender.send()` line resolves the error because it removes the await point.

The simplest way I can think to address this would be to replace `RefCell` with a threadsafe interior mutability implementation such as `RwLock`. There may be a more efficient solution, but it's hard to suggest one without being able to see all of your code that interacts with the `RefCell`; you may not even need interior mutability.

Comment: Hmm... Now that I think about it, both should be `Sync` and `RefMut` should also be `Send`, no?

Comment: Actually, no, `Ref` cannot be `Sync` because it offers `clone()`. About `RefMut` I'm not sure, because it offers `map_split()`.

Comment: Ok I realized that I needed at least enough code to fully characterize what I'm seeing.  I've posted an edit that reflects this.  I'm not familiar with RwLock, so I'm researching that now.  I'm definitely on the steep part of the learning curve of this problem.

Comment: So, `RefMut` cannot be `Send` but it can be `Sync`. I'm going to send a PR.

Comment: I definitely don't need the mutability.  At this point, I'm just looking for a way to get a reference to a channel created outside of the tokio::spawn and send a message to it.  I don't need to pass anything more complex than a string or bool.

Comment: @PilotGuy Looking at the code you've pasted, I don't see why you need the `RefCell` layer at all. You clone the `RefCell` _which clones its contents_ (`RefCell` is not a reference-counted smart pointer), then you give the owned clone to the task. Did you perhaps intend to use `Arc` instead of `RefCell`? It seems like you are using `RefCell` without knowing what it does.

Comment: RefCell came out of my ignorance of how to handle lifetimes across tokio::spawn.  I'm (relatively) new to Rust, so I've been trying different variants of solutions to satisfy the compiler.  Originally, when I just passed a reference to the HashMap, it complained.  I read about RefCell and thought it might solve the issue -- which it *did* for that one error message.  But once I added the send code, i was back to non-funcitoning code.  I'm all ears for suggestions.  I've been banging my head on this problem for three days.

Comment: @PilotGuy All `RefCell` does is let you go from `&RefCell<T>` to `&mut T`, which you do not need in this case. Most likely cloning the `HashMap` is what resolved the issue, because in the code you pasted the task owns the `RefCell<HashMap>`. If the `HashMap` is immutable at this point and you just need to give the same map to a bunch of different tasks for reading only, move it into an `Arc` and clone the `Arc` for each task. This will let you share ownership of the `HashMap` between tasks; `Arc` doesn't count as a reference because it's not a borrow.

Comment: Thank you!  I tested this by removing everything and doing a straight clone, which worked.  In my mind, I was trying to avoid the clone because this has the potential to be called over 200k/s.  I'll work on the Arc implementation.   So, for full disclosure, moving all of this around helped me understand that the compiler was not disposing items as fast as I thought it would.  I was able to add brackets to help scope the variables and eliminate the error.  I'll mark your answer as correct given that you did point me in the right direction.  Thank you!

Comment: @PilotGuy No problem. If avoiding cloning the `HashMap` is imperative for performance and it won't be modified at this point, then there is no reason not to use `Arc`. `Arc::clone()` is cheap and under the hood is just an atomic increment of a reference counter.

Comment: Made a PR: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/115157.